# Filtering with table generated list of dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone help me figure out why this query

```
select *,to_date("datetime") as dt 
from table1
where "env"='mmt'
and dt in 
(select dateadd(day, '-' || seq4(), current_date()) as dt
from table (generator(rowcount => 5)));
```

it throwing all dates from `table1` instead just dates defined with

```
select dateadd(day, '-' || seq4(), current_date()) as dt
    from table (generator(rowcount => 5))
```

Comment: Works for me on a table I have, so might be something related to your table.

Comment: Hmm, can't figure it out. Basic filtering with date works fine.

Comment: So something like this works fine? SELECT to_date("datetime") as dt from table1 where dt in "<date>"